# Run two functions sequentially with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two functions. I need to run fOne() before fTwo().

```
function fOne() {
   if ($('.container').width() < 300) {
    $('.box').each(function(){
          $(this).removeClass('largeSize').addClass('smallSize');
    });
   }
 }

function fTwo() {

    var el = $('.myElement');

    $(el).each(function() {
        var pcntH = el.height(),
            scorH = el.parent().find('.box').outerHeight(true),
            pcntT = scorH - pcntH - 5;

        el.css({'position':'relative', 'top': pcntT + 'px'}).fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
fOne().done(fTwo());
```

That's the idea, but does not work...

Comment: Neither function is an async function - so just run them in order.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to do a callback (so when you call `fOne()`, it will immediately call `fTwo()`), I believe using `.done()` as you mentioned would work. You could also consider using [`$.callbacks()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/) but that might be a little extreme for your situation.

Comment: @George The first one resizes elements and the second is calculating based on the new sizes. I tried it this way but the second one is still using dimensions that were available on page load...

Comment: Can you create a live demo of your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a callback function. In the definition of

```
function fOne(callback) {
   if ($('.container').width() < 300) {
    $('.box').each(function(){
          $(this).removeClass('largeSize').addClass('smallSize');
    });
   }
   callback();
 }
```

and then make the call `fOne(fTwo);`. You are set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not calling them asynchronously fOne(); fTwo(); should work, otherwise have fOne(); return fTwo();

Answer (score 0):

jQuerys `when` and `done` can be used to do an async operation because they use Deffereds. The function that is sent to `when` will be executed and only once that function is completed will it call the function defined by `done`.

```
$.when( fOne() ).done( function() { fTwo(); } );
```

You can check it out at [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: Should you be calling the functions there or passing by reference?

Comment: @ialarmedalien Good call.  Updated.